# Edit XPS content

Tags: c#, printing, xps

I have got an application that is supposed to send a formatted document to a printer with some barcodes.

I've made other applications that work with printers and print directly through the printserver by sending a xps file, so I thought I would try to see if I could make a .xps file, change the text and be done with it, however every article I can find on the net has to do with creating xps files and not changing them. I feel like it should be possible, and it would be nice not to have to resort to installing Office on the server and print through there. Then I might as well use Open XML and a .docx file.

[image: Barcode image]
It is very simple. Let's say I want to change the text *INCNUMMER* in a .xps file to "*testing123*". How would I go about that?

I have tried the whole unzip, open the xml, find the text, edit, rezip but I'm afraid there's too much about the .xps format I don't understand to make that work.

Best regards, Kaspar.

Comment: There's a native Windows API available to work with XPS documents as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316976.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already know, an XPS file is just a ZIP archive containing a number of files and folders that have particular names and a defined structure.

At the root level there is a `Documents` folder which will typically contain just a single document folder named `1`. Inside that is a `Pages` folder containing one or more `.fpage` files: these define the content of each page in the document.

```
Documents
    1
        Pages
            1.fpage
            2.fpage
            etc
```

If you open up these `.fpage` files in a text editor you will see that they are just XML files. Each page is typically represented by a `<Canvas>` element that contains multiple `<Path>` and `<Glyphs>` elements (text is represented by the latter). However, even though `<Glyphs>` elements do have a `UnicodeString` attribute the value of that attribute cannot be changed in isolation.

Each `<Glyphs>` element also has an `Indices` attribute. If you remove this attribute altogether and change the `UnicodeString` attribute at the same time, this *almost* works. However, you will probably find that when viewing the file in the XPS Viewer application certain characters in the text are replaced by question mark symbols.

Font glyphs are embedded in the XPS file (`odttf` files in the `Resources` folder), and the software that generated the XPS file will only embed glyphs that are used in the source document. For example, this means that (for a given font) if you did not use the letter "A" in the source document, then the glyph for that letter will not be written to the resources of the XPS file. Hence if you change the `UnicodeString` attribute to include a letter "A" then that character will display as a question mark in the viewer because it has no glyph resource that tells it how that character must be drawn.

If you have control over the source document (the one that later gets converted to XPS) then I suppose you could include a piece of text containing all of the characters that you are likely to use, and set its colour to white so that it doesn't print, but I'm not sure whether the XPS printer driver would strip that text out anyway. If it *didn't* then you could probably do something like this:

- Open the relevant `.fpage` XML file
- Search all `UnicodeString` attributes of `<Glyphs>` elements to find the text you want
- Replace that text with something else
- Remove the `Indices` attribute from the changed `<Glyphs>` elements
- Save the updated XML back to the file
- Re-zip then change the extension from ZIP to XPS

Comment: That pointed me excatcly in the direction I needed!
I had tried unzipping it and findling with the xml but got some strange results.
Adding a line containing "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" i font-size 1, colored white, enabled me to change the content of the glyphs, when also taking care to add extra indices. I'll accept this as the solution.

Comment: I have the same problem right now and I don't have access to the source XPS. Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524172/question-marks-in-xps-document

Comment: @Steven, Where we can see the .fpage files?

Comment: @SaravanakumarNatarajan It says in the answer: _"At the root level there is a `Documents` folder which will typically contain just a single document folder named `1`. Inside that is a `Pages` folder containing one or more .fpage files"._